# Use model's property as the type for an action parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, model-binding

I have a ViewModel called MainViewModel and inside of it I have property of type MainFilterViewModel. Is it possible to have my action just like `public ActionResult actionName(MainFilterViewModel filter)` and returning `return View(new MainViewModel(){...})`, so I don't have to add the entire ViewModel class?

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public MainFilterViewModel Filter {get;set;}
    public List<GridItem> Rows {get;set;}
}

public class MainFilterViewModel
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public String City {get;set;}
}
```

**View** (just to illustrate)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "TheController", FormMethod.Post, new { Id = "formPrincipal" }))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Filter.Name)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Filter.City)
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btnFilter" value="Filter" />
}
<div id="data-table">
    @* Looping the Rows collection *@
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult ActionName(MainFilterViewModel filter)
{
    // Request data from repository based on filter parameter
    var model = new MainViewModel();
    // fill model with info from the repository
    return View(model);
}
```

BTW, I tried searching for action parameters of a model inner type/property and found nothing.

Comment: Are you only wanting to update a certain section of your View with the details of your MainFilterViewModel or MainViewModel ? In that case, make use of Partial Views and AJax calls

Comment: When the submit button is pressed I need to get the filtered data and update the data-table div, but I don't need to use Ajax for it.

Comment: Sure you don't, but it would make your page not flicker/Refresh, as at the moment you are sending data to server, basically doing a round trip. If you used ajax, and only updated the "data-table" div section, would give your user a more friendly experience, but in the end, it is your choice.

Comment: You could use the FormData collection or possibly write a custom model binding: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2009/04/27/6-tips-for-asp-net-mvc-model-binding.aspx

Comment: Short answer - Yes. But you will need to specify the view name (to be the same as the the view you used in the initial GET method) - `return View("...", model);`. However you will get better performance using ajax to return a partial view of just the filtered collection.

Comment: Let me explain what I need to fix. I have some filters, a grid (using for loop to display rows) and paging links created by PagedListPager (https://github.com/troygoode/PagedList). This links makes GET requests, thus the filters are ignored when navigating between pages. I'm not using partials for this and the view is the same from the initial request, it's the index action/view.

Comment: Then what problems are you having. If the filters are being, its because you are not passing them to the method (i.e. in the `page => Url.Action(...)`. Perhaps if you show your real code, we can help.